# Viewport3D/BitmapExporter (WPF) doesn't Work in Web Apps

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-web-app-service, helix-3d-toolkit

In my website, it allows user to upload a 3D model file (.stl, .obj), and the site will generate a thumbtnail image for it. It works well in my local pc, but it doesn't work in azure, only an empty image was generated without any exception (the background can be drawn, but the object cannot be rendered). Is there any restriction in website apps?

```
public static void Export(Model3DGroup model, string outputFileName)
{
    var viewport = new Viewport3D();

    viewport.Measure(new Size(320, 240));
    viewport.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, 320, 240));

    var root = new ModelVisual3D();
    viewport.Children.Add(root);

    var camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    camera.Position = new Point3D(2, 16, 20);
    camera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(-2, -16, -20);
    camera.UpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
    camera.FieldOfView = 45;
    camera.NearPlaneDistance = 0.1;
    camera.FarPlaneDistance = double.PositiveInfinity;

    viewport.Camera = camera;

    root.Children.Add(new DefaultLights());

    root.Content = model;

    CameraHelper.ZoomExtents(camera, viewport);
    Viewport3DHelper.Export(viewport, outputFileName, Brushes.WhiteSmoke);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the toolkit you are using and your question on their forums [here](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/issues/168), ***If it is working on IIS Express and not on Azure WebApps then it is clear that Helix ToolKit is using a method that is calling into the OS level directX code which may be restricted by the WebApp Worker VM Sandbox***.

**Azure WebApps has a Sandbox that runs you user code on the VMs and as a preventive measure to protect the VMs from being corrupted** it rejects particular calls going directly against the kernel and graphics.

As a work around try out the Azure Cloud Service, it gives you more freedom for scenarios like yours.

Comment: Thank you Chibi! It looks like have to build a webservice on VM for that.